# How do i make the player jump towards the cursor in pygame/pygame-ce

Tags: python, math, pygame, trigonometry

I have a game which looks like this:
[image: Image of the angle i want to find]

The idea is that the ninja will jump towards the green cross - the cursor in-game. And (correct me if I'm wrong) I think the best way to do so is using cosinus and sinus of the angle, to find respectively the x and y components, and then multiply the result with some arbitrary jump force.

I've tried searching the internet to find a solution to my problem with no luck. I do not have a lot of experience with trigonometry, so i do not understand how exactly all tan, cos, sin, arctan and all that works. I just know cos and sin of an angle works for x and y.

I've gotten the most promising result using

```
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
angle = math.atan2(mouse[1], mouse[0]))
print(angle)
```

This returns a value from 90 at the left edge of the screen, to 0 at the top of the screen. This seems correct, but only in the top-left quarter of the screen.

Comment: `math.atan2(mouse[1] - player.y, mouse[0] - player.x))`

Comment: If you mean "towards" just as "left, right, or straight up", then the "duplicate close" is incorrect.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Would i need to add the position of the player when its position is always fixed to 0, 0? It would in all cases be `mouse[1] - 0, mouse[0] - p`

Comment: The position of the player cannot be (0, 0), because (0, 0) is the top left of the screen. `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` always gives a position relative to the top left of the screen. With `math.atan2(my, mx)`, `mx` and `my` needs to be relative to the player. But the mouse position is always relative to the screen.

Comment: Still `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` is relative to the top left of the screen and not relative to your local player coordinates system.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I think I understand now. I need to add the players position relative to the screen. Not its world position. So as the player is centered on the screen, something like `mouse.x +- display.get_width() / 2`

Comment: To make them on the same coordinate system. Whether it’s the local one or the screen one then does not matter.